# How to update all packages in an unattended way?

Tags: r, package, updates

I want an unattended solution to update all packages in current R version, therefore I wrote a function which works satisfactorily in essence.

```
updPcks <- function() {
  l <- length(.packages()) != 7  # check if 'other' packages are loaded
  if (l) {
    lapply(paste('package:', names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs), sep=""), detach,
           character.only=TRUE, unload=TRUE)  # unload 'other' packages
  }
  update.packages(ask=FALSE)
}
```

However there are at least two cases the process is interrupted by dialog boxes popping up, e.g.

> **"Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?"**

and

> **"Would you like to use a personal library instead?"**

For the moment and sake of time saving it would suffice if just ***"no"*** was selected (but avoiding a downgrade!) in this (and other) cases.

There might error messages be thrown or warnings respectively, where I don't want the update process to be stopped. Anyway all information on failure and success in the console should be preserved as in a manual update process.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.1.19
```

Comment: To avoid "Would you like to use a personal library instead?" you should specify a `lib.loc` to which you have write access.

Comment: And you can use `type="source"` to always install from source.

Comment: @aocall Thanks, but as stated I just want to select "no" in such cases and deal with them manually later.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that. To avoid the issue, you could simply run R as an administrator, which should ensure you have write access